# Pod template for specifying tolerations when running Spark on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, kubernetes-pod

I am having some issues when trying to launch Spark jobs via the Kubernetes scheduler.

I want all my driver/executor pods to be spawned onto nodes which has a certain taint. Because of this, I want to specify tolerations which will be directly injected into the pods configuration files. Currently, there is no default way directly from the `spark-submit` command

According to [this](https://github.com/palantir/k8s-spark-scheduler#usage) and [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/running-on-kubernetes.md#pod-template), a user should be able to specify a pod template which can be set with the following parameters: `spark.kubernetes.driver.podTemplateFile` and `spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile`.

I tried specifying those parameters in the `spark-submit` command with the following file:

`pod_template.template`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: dedicated
    operator: Equal
    value: test
```

However, this toleration never gets added to the launched driver pod. Is currently a way to solve this?

For reference, here is the full spark-submit command:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.persistent.options.claimName=pvc-storage --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.persistent.mount.subPath=test-stage1/spark --conf spark.executor.memory=1G --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.persistent.mount.subPath=test-stage1/spark --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=test-stage1 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.persistent.mount.path=/persistent --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.memory=3G --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.persistent.mount.path=/persistent --conf spark.submit.deployMode=cluster --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<SPARK IMAGE> --conf spark.master=k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=1  --conf spark.executor.cores=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.persistent.options.claimName=pvc-storage --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile=//opt/pod_template.template --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.podTemplateFile=//opt/pod_template.template local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py 100
```

Answer (score 6):

I have checked various documentations and found few things that might be misconfigured here:

1. Your `pod_template.template` should have the `.yaml` at the end
2. You did not specify `spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name` in your `spark-submit` command nor in the `pod_template.template.yaml` in a form of `metadata`
3. You have used double `//` when specifing path for `spark.kubernetes.driver.podTemplateFile=` and `spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile=`
4. You should put all your tolerations in `""`, for example: `effect: "NoSchedule"`

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: @toerq Did any of the above help?

Comment: This helped me, thanks for the notes.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which version of Spark is used? I don't think `spark.kubernetes.driver.podTemplateFile` and `spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile` is available until Spark 3.0.

Here is the [Spark JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24434) which added support for above 2 configuration options. It's only resolved for Spark 3.0 branch.